# Decoding an UTF-8 string to Windows-1256

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I used this code to encode a UTF-8 string to Windows-1256 string:

```
        string q = textBox1.Text;
        UTF7Encoding utf = new UTF7Encoding();

        byte[] winByte = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(q);

        string result = utf.GetString(winByte);
```

This code is working but I can't decode the result or encoded to original string!
How I can decode an encoded string (result variable) to same before converted (q variable)?

Comment: Your title says UTF-8 but your code says UTF-7...? Also, do you have any idea how encodings even work?

Comment: I found above code by Test and Errors. I want to code a text box to use in lemur project and then decode result lemur show on other text box. The coding by above code and it work well but I can't decoding result.

Answer (score 4):

You are converting the strings incorrectly.

Have a look at the commented code below. The comments explain what is wrong, and how to do it correctly, but basically what is happening is:

Firstly you use `Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(q)` to convert a string (which is UTF16) to an ANSI codepage 1256 string.

Then you use a UTF7 encoding to convert it back. But that's wrong because you need to use an ANSI codepage 1256 encoding to convert it back:

```
string q = "ABئبئ"; // UTF16.
UTF7Encoding utf = new UTF7Encoding(); // Used to convert UTF16 to/from UTF7

// Convert UTF16 to ANSI codepage 1256. winByte[] will be ANSI codepage 1256.
byte[] winByte = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(q);

// Convert UTF7 to UTF16.
// But this is WRONG because winByte is ANSI codepage 1256, NOT UTF7!
string result = utf.GetString(winByte);

Debug.Assert(result != q); // So result doesn't equal q

// The CORRECT way to convert the ANSI string back:
// Convert ANSI codepage 1256 string to UTF16

result = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(winByte);

Debug.Assert(result == q); // Now result DOES equal q
```

Comment: You assume that you have a result variable that encoded by utf.GetString(winByte), How you can decode without original text. Actually the result a function of lemur is coded like this.

Comment: @user1490377 Not sure what you mean. You don't need the original text to decode, you just need the bytes of data to be decoded and knowledge of which decoder to use.